# Global link instead of localhost in a VM oracle ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a VM Ubuntu (powered by oracle VM) and my operation System is Windows Server 2012 r2.

In VM I run locally a webpage under `127.0.0.1:3838/myshinyapp/`

I would like to use instead of 127.0.0.1 an address from my server in order to give a public link.

Because I don't know many things from networks is it possible to make from a Ubuntu VM located in a Windows Server operation system have a global url (open ports etc.)?

More specifically:

- in the Ubuntu VM the shiny server listen to the port 3838
- the windows server 2012 r2 has a specific global link (general example) mywindowsserver.som.com under this I can make port available from windows server in this format mywindowsserver.som.com:port

However how can I do the result from local host in Ubuntu VM be available under mywindowsserver.som.com